# XML instead of JSON with Grape, Rails 3 and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, json, heroku, grape-api

I am using Grape (https://github.com/intridea/grape) with Rails 3 and i am experiencing a strange problem.

I defined json as the default output format in my API class, and i am using the as_json method to output my results.

In my /lib/MyAPI.rb:

```
class MyAPI < Grape::API
  prefix 'api'
  version 'v1', :using => :path, :format => :json, :default_format => :json

  resource "users" do
    get do
      error!("401 invalid token", 401) unless current_user
  users = User.where('id != ?' , current_user.id) - current_user.friends
       users.as_json()
    end
  end 
end
```

In developement mode, the json is correclty rendered, however on heroku xml is rendered instead of json.

Does somebody know why ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Have you the same issue if you run your application in production mode in your local server ?

Comment: In production mode in my local server, it works correclty. It looks like the problem comes from heroku. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you paste log of your heroku instance when you call your API ?

Comment: there is not a lot of info `2012-04-05T09:07:32 +00:00 heroku[router]: GET *****.com/api/v1/me dyno=web.1 queue=O wait=0ms service=118ms status=200 bytes=813`

Comment: can you add some output in your action like env ?

Comment: if i add `.json` to request url , it works!! The output is in json. 
It is a good news but i don't understand why i need it since i defined json as the default format and it works correcty in my local server.

Answer (score 3):

In according to the README and code. In the Grape 0.2.0 version, `default_format` is not an option of version class method. You need fix it by your class :

```
class MyAPI < Grape::API
  prefix 'api'
  version 'v1', :using => :path
  format :json
  default_format :json

  resource "users" do
    get do
      error!("401 invalid token", 401) unless current_user
  users = User.where('id != ?' , current_user.id) - current_user.friends
       users.as_json()
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion but get the following error : `/Users/mathieuripert/woudu/lib/MyAPI.rb:4:in `format': can't convert Symbol into String (TypeError)`

Comment: which version of grape you use ?